# How to determine when my list exists, but is empty?

Tags: redis

I just learned that when a list is empty, EXISTS returns 0.

I am processing a list using this:

```
rpoplpush source target
```

When I am done processing, I still want to look at the `source` to see if it is empty, but also if the key exists.  But since the list is empty, it is returning **0**.

```
EXISTS source
(integer) 0
```

**Is there a way to know that your list is empty, but the key does exist still in redis?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In redis, empty list can't exist. If after popping an element list becomes empty, [it is deleted](https://github.com/antirez/redis/blob/d680eb6dbdf2d2030cb96edfb089be1e2a775ac1/src/t_list.c#L380-L383).

```
    if (listTypeLength(o) == 0) {
        notifyKeyspaceEvent(NOTIFY_GENERIC,"del",
                            c->argv[1],c->db->id);
        dbDelete(c->db,c->argv[1]);
    }
```

Comment: I see, so if I need to keep track if a list was created, I have to create another key then.